# Understanding A* Search on Tropical Island

Tags: algorithm, path, graph-algorithm, a-star

I am working on an online MOOC on AI and I am now working to understand A* better.

Basically, right now I am working on a problem where: we live on a tropical island and we're trying to navigate between areas, starting from `d` and heading towards `q`.

[image]

I am trying to find the cost used between `d` and `q` using `A*` search; and also how many 'nodes' that we're opened during the search.

Below is the costs (when travelling to nodes)

[image]

Below is the distance to the target

[image]

**Attempt at Solving**

The optimal path from `d` to `q` is d->e->f->g->l->n->q with which would give me a cost of 50+70+20+60+45+20 = 265. This looks like it is the optimal path to get from d to q as well.

Also, we should be expanding 1+2+2+3+1+1=10 nodes to find this path with A*.

Can any of you AI gurus help me confirm whether I am understanding this properly?

*Thanks a ton in advance!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. In this special case of A*, you're dealing with a uniform-cost search, since the heuristic is a constant function.

I got 265 as the distance. Are you counting the root among the expanded nodes? Because I got 10 nodes if I include the root.

Comment: Cool thanks, I wasn't sure if I was doing this right! Would you also know how to calculate the number of `cycles` detected?

Comment: You can keep a stack or hashmap of visited nodes as you are expanding them. Then if that stack/hashmap contains the next node in your worklist then you have a cycle.

Comment: So that would be `2`, ..I believe? Because it see's the loop at `c`? Hmm, bit confused on that.

Comment: Yes, there are two loops. After you expand `f`, you get to `g` with a distance of 140. The next node to expand is `c`, which has the distance of 130 and you can get to `g`, so that is a loop. The other one is the large outer loop.

Comment: Hmm, what is the large outer loop. I see the `c` loop but now I think that there is only one loop.

Comment: The outer loop is e-j-p-r-q-n-l-g-f-e. You will get to `k` on a distance of 300, to `r` on a distance of 235 and to `n` on a distance of 245, so you will expand `r` to get to `q` on a distance of 475. Since 475 > 245, you expand `n` and get to `q` with 265 which is less than `k`'s 300 so you're done.